# Visual Studio Code - how to add a vim editor command?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to bind ":W" editor command to save the file just like ":w". I make a lot of this typos.

The vim plugin is: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim

This settings.json code doesn't work:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
  {
    "before": [":","W"],
    "commands": [
      "workbench.action.files.save"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: command mode mappings do not seem to be possible at the moment in vs code vim. see here https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2903

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible in vs code vim, but I ended up doing what [bsaf suggested here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2903#issuecomment-422947244) and rebound `:` to `;` so that I wouldn't accidentally be holding shift down while pressing `w`, which doesn't solve the problem you asked but it does solve the problem you mentioned in your post. You can do this by adding this to your settings.json file:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
  {
     "before": [";"],
     "after": [":"]
   }
]
```

You can still use `:` as normal, but now `;` will also allow you to run editor commands.